# Is there a way to call function "a" which calls next() on the iterable/yielding function "b"

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I have 2 functions as shown:

```
def num():
  for number in range(1, 5):
    yield number

def config_btn():
  global rad_btn1, rad_btn2, rad_btn3, rad_btn4
  c = next(num())

  temp_entry.config(text=f'{iterate_questions(2)}'),
  # temp_entry.config(state=DISABLED)

  rad_btn1.config(text=f'{iterate_answer_choices(c, 1).title()}', indicatoron=0),

  rad_btn2.config(text=f'{iterate_answer_choices(c, 2).title()}', indicatoron=0),

  rad_btn3.config(text=f'{iterate_answer_choices(c, 3).title()}', indicatoron=0),

  rad_btn4.config(text=f'{iterate_answer_choices(c, 4).title()}', indicatoron=0)
```

def num() is a function that yields numbers 1 through 5 when iterated (i hope), and config_btn uses the previous function to assign a number to "c". "c" is then passed to another function. Is there a way I can  call config_btn from outside these functions to have "c" change to the next number and proceed with the rest of the function?

I have tried altering the config_btn to accept a number and passed

Comment: Values yielded in num() are 1,2,3,4

Comment: Yes.... but when i call the config_btn function, it keeps assigning 1 to "c" so not sure what's keeping it from getting the next number (2) and assigning it to "c"

Comment: because you keep calling `num()`.

Comment: `num` returns an *object* that yields successive values. `next(num())` creates that object, passes it to `num`, then discards the object. `n = num(); next(n); next(n); # etc.`

Comment: `def config_btn(c):`, `....`, `config_btn(next(num()))`

Comment: Also, `num` is just `range(1,6)`.

Comment: @chepner I see what you're saying and i did what you stated, but the config_btn function is still not calling the next number (2) from the num() function. i did d-num(); c=next(d);

and yes, I plan on changing the range() to another set of data.

Comment: @Jorgen no, **you keep creating a new generator** when you use `num()`, you'd have to create it once and keep using it, not every time you call the function (e.g. by passing it in as an argument, although, you should probably just pass whatever `c` is supposed to be)

Comment: @chepner I got it!! I did what you said and then i created d=num() OUTSIDE of either function. Now I can do c = next(d) when i set d to global.  Also, I would just pass "c" but i reuse the same buttons that autoupdate (from data in a dictionary soon)

Thank you!! Also, can i mark this as solved?

Comment: @Jorgen that's really not a great way of doing, though. global state is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an other global variable does not bother you, you can do this :

```py
def num():
  for number in range(1, 5):
    yield number

c = num()

def config_btn():
  global rad_btn1, rad_btn2, rad_btn3, rad_btn4, c
  next(c)

  temp_entry.config(text=f'{iterate_questions(2)}'),
  # temp_entry.config(state=DISABLED)

  rad_btn1.config(text=f'{iterate_answer_choices(c, 1).title()}', indicatoron=0),

  rad_btn2.config(text=f'{iterate_answer_choices(c, 2).title()}', indicatoron=0),

  rad_btn3.config(text=f'{iterate_answer_choices(c, 3).title()}', indicatoron=0),

  rad_btn4.config(text=f'{iterate_answer_choices(c, 4).title()}', indicatoron=0)
```

However it does not seems clean. There must be a better way.
Then you have to handle the `StopIteration` error thrown at the 5th iteration, if it goes so far.

Comment: Oh my god... Thank you!! I haven't touched generators in months and completely forgot about this. And you're right, it's definitely not clean and I need a not-so clean try/catch statement as well. I've been stuck on this step for a class project for a few days. Now I can move on and clean up later. Thanks, buddy!!

Comment: Cool :) Then keep going